# Python Json create a list in a jsonfile with a name

Tags: python, json

I have a json file that I want to write in many different lists. To access them later on,  they need to have a name in the json file. I've only managed to dump in one list, which has not got a key in the file. So how can I do it so that the list in the json file has a name like down below the "data" list.

from:

```
list = []

with open("jsonfile.json", "w") as f:
     json.dump(list, f, indent=4)
```

to:

```
{
    "list": [
        
    ]
    
}
```

Comment: Please share an example of your input and your desired output. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Simply dump a dictionary, with the keys being the names you want to assign to the lists, and the values being the lists you want to store:

```
lst = []  # the list you want to store

data = {
    "list": lst
}

with open("jsonfile.json", "w") as f:
     json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Be aware not to use `list` as a variable name, since it is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple lists, convert them to a dictionary first and then dump that to json. You can create a naming scheme to create keys using something like the following:

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
dict_of_lists = {'list_'+str(i): list for i,list in enumerate(list_of_lists)}

with open("jsonfile.json", "w") as f:
     json.dump(dict_of_lists, f, indent=4)
```